# Is it possible configure Visual Studio menu alignment?

Tags: visual-studio, menu, visual-studio-2022

**Context**

I am using VS 2022 for a month or more. I tried to get used to its menu alignment and submenu placement, but now I am giving up. It is still a continuous distraction point and productivity killer for me.

I do not know if it is the VS 2022 application itself or some Windows 11 thing, and can not recall how VS 2019 behaved on Windows 10...

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way to configure how the menu items are aligned and which direction the submenu opens?

Comment: Have you maybe set your PC to "left-handed" mode? [link](https://irishdotnet.dev/how-to-revert-back-visual-studio-menu-alignment)

Comment: ... although the settings there seem counter-intuitive.

Comment: BTW, I checked the actions suggested in the link I gave and, selecting a different radio-button in the popup does, indeed, change the alignment of the menus in Visual Studio (but I have Windows 10 and VS 2019).

Comment: @AdrianMole: many thx, good shoot. Unfortunatelly, when I bring up the Tablet PC settings, there is only one tab: "Display", so there is no "Other' tab with handedness settings...

Comment: ...however based on your idea, I found the registry setting: MenuDropAlignment (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows). This seems to be a WPF thing too, and its value was '1'  in my machine. WPF and VS 2022 behaves weird. It seems all other applications (like Windows Shell,  Office ) disregard this settings, and regardless its value of 1, behaved normally. However VS 2022 "honors" this setting, and behaves counterintuitive, so I set the value to 0, and bingo, now VS 2022 behaves just like any other application.

Comment: In case you are post it as answer, I am going to accept it.

Comment: It looks like you should post an answer. Specifically [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485035/is-it-possible-configure-visual-studio-menu-alignment-the-current-behavior-is-a#comment124597647_70485035) seems like the answer...

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Adrian's valuable comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70485035/is-it-possible-configure-visual-studio-menu-alignment/70503240#comment124596823_70485035) and [How to revert back Visual Studio menu alignment](https://irishdotnet.dev/how-to-revert-back-visual-studio-menu-alignment) blog post:

Following the instructions the blog article above (use Tablet PC Settings -> "Other" tab -> Handedness) unfortunately, when I bring up the Tablet PC Settings, there is only one tab: "Display", so there is no "Other" tab with handedness settings on my machine...

...however based on this handedness idea, I found the registry setting: `MenuDropAlignment` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`). This seems to be **a WPF thing too**, and its value was '1' in my machine, do not ask why... maybe somewhere in the new Windows 11 setup, I answered a question being left handed :-)

This does not change the fact, that WPF and VS 2022 behaves weird. It seems *all other applications (like Windows Shell, Office ) disregard this setting*, and regardless its value of 1, **behaved normally**.

However VS 2022 "honors" this setting, and behaves counterintuitive, so I set the value to 0, and bingo, now VS 2022 behaves just like any other application.

Comment: Not working for me :( I set the value to 0 (the value existed and was 1) but VS2022 does not revert to normal menus.